# How to do pandas-like shift operation on an arquero table (or other tables) for plotting in ObservableHQ?

Tags: observablehq

For example, you might have something like this in your plotting spec for a scatter:

```
{"data": {"values": mydata.select("x", "y")}, ... }
```

But suppose you want to plot `mydata.select("x").slice(5)` vs `mydata.select("y").slice(-5)` ... is there a fast or inline way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of slicing an array in JavaScript, the easiest probably being Array.slice(); it returns a new array with the copied data.

For performance, if the array is a typed array and you just want to read from it, you'll want to use Array.subarray() instead.

Arquero itself has a *slice* verb, which returns a sliced view (again, without copying the data).

If your data is a generic iterable, you can also convert it to an array then slice that array: Array.from(data).slice(…)